# How to display my PC's IP Address on Windows (7) Startup?

Tags: cmd, ipv4

I am on a work computer with dynamic IP address (Ipv4), which usually changes when I restart it. Since I sometimes need to use this PC through remote desktop connection at home I like to keep its IP address handy. But I sometimes forget to check the IP at restart, so is there a batch file or some code which can start up the cmd and display the IPv4 address everytime the computer restarts ?
thanks.

Comment: Your work computer is given a public IP address? Hooked directly up to the Internet?? That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a batch file to run upon startup.
The batch file should contain:

```
ipconfig
pause
```

Comment: Thanks Avi. the "pause" part helps, since when I was trying to run a batch file, the prompt opened and closed too quickly to see anything.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just create a batch file that runs [`ipconfig`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ipconfig.mspx) and displays the output:

```
start cmd /k ipconfig
exit
```

You'll see a console window appear on your screen each time you execute this batch file that contains the output of the `ipconfig` command. Among the information displayed will be the IP address for each of your computer's network adapters.

You can configure the command as appropriate, adding switches to `ipconfig` as desired. For example, adding the `/all` switch will cause additional information to be displayed.

If you wanted, you could parse the output of `ipconfig`, extract the IP address assigned to a particular network adapter, and display just that on the screen. That might reduce the cognitive overload. But any good Windows sysadmin can scan the output of `ipconfig` rather easily.

Comment: thanks Cody. that gets the job done. If I want to add the <find "IPv4"> part into this command, what syntax should I use ? if i may as, what does the "/k" part signify ?

Answer (score 1):

I used this in a .bat file I created some days ago and it works fine:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set ip=%%b
set ip=%ip:~1%

echo %ip%
```

This way the IP is defined as a variable named "ip", so you can use this to do other things with your current IP.

I hope it helped somehow.